# 2 char в структуру потом в int и обратно

Tags: c++, arduino, преобразование-типов

Нужно объект из структуры два байта преобразовать в int два байта, передать по порту между ESP к arduino иле обратно, а потом в назад преобразовать в структуру.

Язык с++, но без библиотек.

```
struct PIN
{
    unsigned char PinAndComand;
    unsigned char PWN;
}; 

PIN obj;
int content;

// content = (int)obj;
// obj = (PIN)content;
```

---

Зачем? В arduino нет возможности передавать структуры через сериал, целиком только int.
А мне нужно из ардуино сделать множитель портов для esp.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему бы не использовать вместо структуры, int.

Года два плата управления комнатой работает только на esp. Но нужно внести изменения, а я прошивку потерял и не помню распиловку. Решил новую сделать адекватно чтобы не боятся притронуться.

Comment: *"В arduino нет возможности передавать структуры через сериал"* - сильное утверждение

Comment: А как? не преобразцовая структуру в массив символов, Я до тог чтоб задать вопрос погуглил и не нашёл.

Comment: Указатель на структуру можно кастануть в указатель на char (это называется storage access). Через последовательный порт же всегда идет просто последовательность байт.

Comment: Допустим, я так понял как в бинарной в файл запись структур . Но какой функцией отправить и принять?

Comment: А чем не устраивает руками собрать из 2 байтов один инт через операции сдвига?

Comment: С каких пор int - 2 байта, а не 4?

Comment: @Qwertiy ви просто с embedded не работаити )

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ , с тех пор, как int объявили платформо-зависимым ? :)

Comment: Прикол, проверил залив скетч с sizeof в arduino тут int байта 2 а на  esp8266 4 байта, кто бы мог подумать. Надеюсь на совместимость при передаче данным  способом не повлияет.  Зачем разработчикам так портить int . Жесть

Comment: @Optimus1, я думал, что платформ с 2 уже давно не осталось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты можешь конвернуть с помощью reinterpret_cast

```
struct PIN
{
    unsigned char PinAndComand;
    unsigned char PWN;
}; 

PIN obj;
int content;

 content = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&obj); // или 
 content = *(int*)(&obj);
 obj = *reinterpret_cast<PIN*>(&content)
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как можно структуру в 4 байта конвертировать в 2 байта без потери данных, у меня два устройства и у каждого своя оперативка, разве данные не будут испорчены?

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка ты так же можешь в два байта передать short например, не инт. short. в чем проблема? тогда структура будет два байта, два unsigned char. Да и потом я конвертирую структуру 4 байта в инт( он тоже 4 байта)

Comment: @Aptem_f, на ардуине int - это 2 байта.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка все нормально, даже делать ничего не придется, бери структуру и моим способом конверти

Comment: Почему-то думал что инт 2 байта, на всякий случай проверю функцией Sizeof в ардуине, Но суть понял если 4 байта действительно то ответ понятен, сегодня попробую.

Comment: @Aptem_f, а кто вам сказал что int должен быть длиной в 32 бита? В стандарте сказано, что размер зависит от платформы.

Answer (score 2):

Берем `union`:

```
union PIN {
    unsigned int i_data;
    
    struct {
        unsigned char pin_and_command;
        unsigned char pwn;
    } s_data; /* имя можно опустить */
};

int
main(void) {
    union PIN pin_data = (union PIN) { 0 };
    
    pin_data.s_data.pin_and_command = 's'; /* для примера */
    pin_data.s_data.pwn = 23;

    int content = pin_data.i_data; /* Вот тебе то что нужно */
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/aUnlKy

Answer (score 1):

Или так:

```
        struct PIN
        {
            unsigned char PinAndComand;
            unsigned char PWN;
        };
        
        
int main()
{
        PIN my_pin;
        int my_int;
        
        my_pin.PinAndComand = 100;
        my_pin.PWN = 2;
        
    
    //--------------------------------------------------
        ((unsigned char*)&my_int)[0] = my_pin.PinAndComand;
        ((unsigned char*)&my_int)[1] = my_pin.PWN;
    //--------------------------------------------------
}
```

Теперь в переменной my_int ваши значения из структуры PIN. Можно передавать этот int куда угодно.